# How can I setup the tab indentation size for ***-mode (Rust, Python, Ruby, etc)?

Tags: indentation, rust

I have rust-mode installed on my Emacs 24.4. The tab indentation I have is 2 whitespaces, however in Rust mode it's different. I want to setup  the tab indentation size for rust-mode, how can I do that?

And actually, not only for rust mode, for other languages such as Python too.

UPDATE:

Or I think it's better for me to setup it globally regardless of the setting for each **-mode package.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can do something like this:

```
(add-hook '<foo>-mode-hook (lambda () (setq tab-width 4)))
```

If you have a single global default you prefer:

```
(setq-default tab-width <number you like>)
```

Comment: what's "a single global default "?

Comment: If you do `C-h v tab-width <RET>`, you'll see, "automatically becomes buffer-local when set." This means that a variable (in this case, `tab-width`) has a default, base value, and expects to be overwritten on a per-buffer basis. For instance: the vanilla emacs default for `tab-width` is 8 spaces. In my configs, I have `(setq-default tab-width 4)` (because 8 is silly), but then in my JavaScript configs I have a hook that sets `tab-width` to 2 spaces.